# SerpentAI: Failed building wheel for Cython

Tags: python, anaconda, cython

The log left in the Anaconda Prompt is so long, I physically can't copy & paste it all. At the moment is that I am currently attempting to follow Serpent.AI's own Windows 10 installation guide on youtube (it was the best one I could find, I'm actually using Windows 7), and I am stopped after attempting to `pip install SerpentAI`.

Within a moment's notice, the installation continues until I see a brief flash of red text whiz by saying `Failed building wheel for Cython`, followed by a massive flood of directories and copying/creating Cython directories.

I have NO clue what I am left with here; I'm warning you, this is about to get ugly.

```
copying Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Distutils
copying Cython\Distutils\extension.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Distutils
copying Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Distutils
copying Cython\Distutils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Distutils
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\Actions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\DFA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\Errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\Lexicons.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\Machines.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\Regexps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\Scanners.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\Timing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\Traditional.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\Transitions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Tests
copying Cython\Tests\TestCodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Tests
copying Cython\Tests\TestJediTyper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Tests
copying Cython\Tests\TestStringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Tests
copying Cython\Tests\xmlrunner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Tests
copying Cython\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Tests
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Build\Tests
copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestInline.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Build\Tests
copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestIpythonMagic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Build\Tests
copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestStripLiterals.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Build\Tests
copying Cython\Build\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Build\Tests
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestBuffer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestCmdLine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestFlowControl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestGrammar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestMemView.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestParseTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestSignatureMatching.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTreeFragment.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTreePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTypes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestUtilityLoad.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestVisitor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler\Tests
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Tempita
copying Cython\Tempita\compat3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Tempita
copying Cython\Tempita\_looper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Tempita
copying Cython\Tempita\_tempita.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Tempita
copying Cython\Tempita\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Tempita
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyximport
copying pyximport\pyxbuild.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyximport
copying pyximport\pyximport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyximport
copying pyximport\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyximport
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger
copying Cython\Debugger\Cygdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger
copying Cython\Debugger\DebugWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger
copying Cython\Debugger\libcython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger
copying Cython\Debugger\libpython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger
copying Cython\Debugger\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger\Tests
copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\TestLibCython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger\Tests
copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\test_libcython_in_gdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger\Tests
copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\test_libpython_in_gdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger\Tests
copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger\Tests
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes
copying Cython\Includes\openmp.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\array.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bool.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\datetime.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\dict.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\exc.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\function.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\instance.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\int.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\long.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\longintrepr.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mem.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\method.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\module.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\number.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\object.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pystate.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pythread.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\ref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\slice.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\type.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\version.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
copying Cython\Includes\cpython\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\cpython
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python2.5.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bool.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_dict.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_exc.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_function.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_instance.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_int.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_long.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mem.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_method.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_module.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_number.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_object.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_ref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_type.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_version.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\errno.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\locale.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\math.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\setjmp.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\stddef.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdint.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\time.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
copying Cython\Includes\libc\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libc
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\algorithm.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\cast.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\deque.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\functional.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\map.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\memory.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\pair.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\queue.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\stack.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeindex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeinfo.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_map.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\utility.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\vector.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\libcpp
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\numpy
copying Cython\Includes\numpy\math.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\numpy
copying Cython\Includes\numpy\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\numpy
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\dlfcn.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\fcntl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\ioctl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\mman.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\resource.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\select.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\stat.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\strings.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\time.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\types.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\unistd.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\wait.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Includes\posix\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Includes\posix
copying Cython\Compiler\Code.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler
copying Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler
copying Cython\Compiler\ParseTreeTransforms.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler
copying Cython\Compiler\Parsing.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler
copying Cython\Compiler\Scanning.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler
copying Cython\Compiler\Visitor.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Compiler
copying Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Runtime
copying Cython\Plex\Actions.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Plex\Scanners.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Plex
copying Cython\Utility\CConvert.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\CpdefEnums.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\CppConvert.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\TestCythonScope.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\TestCyUtilityLoader.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\Buffer.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\Builtins.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\Capsule.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\CMath.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\CommonStructures.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\Complex.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\Coroutine.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\CythonFunction.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\Embed.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\Exceptions.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\ExtensionTypes.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\FunctionArguments.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\ImportExport.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView_C.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\ModuleSetupCode.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\ObjectHandling.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\Optimize.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\Overflow.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\Printing.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\Profile.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\StringTools.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\TestUtilityLoader.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\TypeConversion.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\arrayarray.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\CppSupport.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\codefile -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger\Tests
copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\cfuncs.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Cython\Debugger\Tests
running build_ext
cythoning C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\Cython\Plex\Scanners.py to C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\Cython\Plex\Scanners.c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\setup.py", line 338, in <module>
    **setup_args
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 185, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 192, in build_extensions
    ext.sources = self.cython_sources(ext.sources, ext)
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 345, in cython_sources
    full_module_name=module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 693, in compile
    return compile_single(source, options, full_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 643, in compile_single
    return run_pipeline(source, options, full_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 455, in run_pipeline
    from . import Pipeline
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\Cython\Compiler\Pipeline.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .Visitor import CythonTransform
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import ExprNodes
  File "C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\Cython\Compiler\ExprNodes.py", line 2844
    await = None
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
--------------------------
Rolling back uninstall of cython
Command "C:\Users\Brenda\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Brenda\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\\Cython\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-r1veoqfn\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Brenda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dmz6b_4l\Cython\
```

Comment: Quick way to get more details on error, can you try with debug on in verbose?

Comment: @Amit If I knew how to capture a complete verbose log from a prompt after running the pip install I would (which i really don't), but it doesn't seem to show much more detail in the end.

Comment: try running pip install with -v flag. Check https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/

Comment: @Amit Okay, here is a pastebin with the log file with the -v flag. Warning, it's about 2.5k lines long. https://pastebin.com/3QTNh3Lj

Answer (score 2):

*Please note SerpentAI [declared End of life](https://github.com/SerpentAI/SerpentAI#warning-end-of-life-november-2018)*

This a problem with Cython. The problem is that Cython 0.26 is incompatible with Python 3.7 because Cython named a variable `await` and the name became a reserved keyword in Python 3.7.

I can think of a few solutions for the problem First, downgrade Python: use Python 3.5 or 3.6.

If you really need Python 3.7 you can clone [SerpentAI sources](https://github.com/SerpentAI/SerpentAI), fix Cython version in `setup.py` and install from the modified sources with `pip install .`