# How to Install SerpentAI without facing the Cython invalid syntax error "await = None"

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have been trying to install SerpentAI by following this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5d4Ceq1L8hg but got stuck when running "pip install SerpentAI" command. The command gives an error when installing the Cython dependency with, "await = None" and "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".
Error is the same as: [SerpentAI: Failed building wheel for Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54085728/serpentai-failed-building-wheel-for-cython)?
But the answer described in that thread gave me the same error as before. (i corrected the spelling of install when running the command)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same problem See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223640/7976758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will downgrade to python 3.6 as suggested in stackoverflow.com/a/54223640/7976758. In CMD the command is 
`conda install python=3.6` when you are in the correct directory. Thanks phd